# Keep git log of a subdirectory, not as a submodule

Tags: git, github

I have two app directories in one github repository and they have separate git logs.

```
$ git rm --cached store_app
rm 'store_app'
$ git rm --cached blog_app
fatal: not removing 'blog_app' recursively without -r
```

Only different thing I did for these two directories, for one I did `git commit` before `git init` of the super directory, and after that for the other. (both subdirectories don't have remote)

```
094-active_resource-basics/store_app$ git commit -m "commit before" # after init and add
094-active_resource-basics$ git init
094-active_resource-basics/blog_app$ git commit -m "commit after"  # after init and add
094-active_resource-basics$ git push # after add and commit
```

Only "blog_app" directory worked as expected. I want to keep the git log of `store_app` directory. And this should not be a "Subproject"

Comment: If you do `git init` at the root, with `store_app` and `blog_app` being a child directory, then both will be part of the Git repository at the root. They will share the same history, the same remote, and will only be some subdirectories in a single project.

Comment: Then when you `git init` at the root, a subdirectory which already a git repo with commits, automatically turn into a "submodule"?

Comment: No, for the root repository, it’s just a folder (since its `.git` folder is automatically ignored). So you would have to keep track of its history in the root *and* the child repository. But no, submodules don’t magically appear.

Comment: But one more question, when `git ls-files --cached` it had `store_app` file and this file updated as I make changes in the folder. such as `Subproject commit 9c29343ddc908a460ccab2276ad77c0794e92734` (but I didn't see any `.gitmodules` file though)

Comment: [A nested repository is a submodule.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26679947/1290731)

Comment: And commit log of `blog_app` couldn't be pushed when I push the root (`.git` in the sub folder was ignored from `.git` of super directory), only see them locally.. I still wanted to keep them in local directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It became not a submodule, after `git init` on the root directory. store_app directory stays submodule here:

```
$ git rm --cached store_app   # index file name
$ git add store_app           # directory name
```

But not here (ignore subdirectory commits):

```
$ git rm --cached store_app
$ git init
$ git add store_app
```

This is interesting to me because a repo becomes a submodule when you move it as a subdirectory to another repo. (with no `.gitmodules`) But you cannot make a subdirectory into subproject by committing in the subdirectory. (of course you will do `git submodule add`) I'm not sure about the use cases if it's a subproject and doesn't have its `.gitmodules` file (only with index file) at the same time in any way.